# QT signals undefined and not triggered in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to use QT signals. I have reviews several documents, but none of them helped. I have a BackendService QML file, where all of the backend functions located. Also I have a main QML file, what is the root. I am trying to update loggedIn variable after auth, but signal seems to be not working.

BackendService.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    property bool userLoggedIn: false
    property string api: "http://localhost:8080"

    signal userLoggedInChangedSignal(bool value)

    onUserLoggedInChanged: {
        userLoggedInChangedSignal(userLoggedIn)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        userLoggedInChangedSignal.connect(test)
    }

    function test(asd){
        console.log(asd)
    }

    function login(username, password) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = api + "/login";
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    userLoggedIn = true;
                } else {
                    console.log('Login error:', xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
                }
            }
        }
        var params = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
        xhr.send(params);
    }
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    BackendService {
        id: backendService
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var test = backendService.userLoggedInChangedSignal.connect(mainWindow.updateView);
        console.log(test)
    }

    function updateView(loggedIn) {
        console.log(loggedIn)
        root.currentIndex = backendService.userLoggedIn ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
// main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView viewer;
    viewer.engine()->addImportPath("qrc:/qml/frontend/");  // Adjust path as needed
    viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/frontend/main.qml"));  // Adjust path as needed
    viewer.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    viewer.setTitle("Task Manager");
    viewer.show();

    QObject::connect(viewer.engine(), &QQmlEngine::quit, &app, &QCoreApplication::quit);

    return app.exec();
}
```

I am using QT 5.14.2

I have tried to use `Connections` tag too, but did not help. `test` variable seems to be undefined. But `backendService` and `userLoggedInChangedSignal` exists and fine.

Comment: Are you getting any output from your console.log() statements? Have you verified that your signal is actually getting sent?

Comment: This line `viewer.engine()->addImportPath("qrc:/qml/frontend/");` should be removed. `addImportPath()` is for something else. I couldn't identify where the `login()` method actually gets called, so, how can you expect to be signal later?

Comment: I did not include the login() call, but based on the console logs it is called. Also property is changed. I can not receive any signal in the other qml file.

Comment: Sometimes, if we do too much initialization in `Component.onCompleted`, things may fire before we had a chance to connect to the signals. Instead, things such as `login` on startup, should be delayed/deferred if possible, e.g. `Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(login)` instead of `Component.onCompleted: login()`.

Comment: For debugging, you should make sure you troubleshoot (1) when login() is called, (2) when signal is being connected, (3) when the signal is being signalled. This may highlight initialization / sequencing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would arrange the SIGNAL/SLOT stuff in another way. More like this (untested). I'm not sure, if you can use '=>' notation in QT 5. In this case you have to use a function:

BackendService.qml:

```
QtObject {
    property bool userLoggedIn: false
    property string api: "http://localhost:8080"

    signal userLoggedInChangedSignal(bool value)

    onUserLoggedIn: {
        // detect change to userLoggedIn property...emit SIGNAL
        userLoggedInChangedSignal(userLoggedIn);

        // optional: call your function test
        test(userLoggedIn);
    }

    function test(asd){
        console.log(asd)
    }

    // rest of your code    
}
```

main.qml

```
BackendService {
    id: backendService

    onUserLoggedInChangedSignal: (test) => {
        console.log(test);
    }

}

// more of your code
```